# Reverse Proxy to VPC-Based AWS Elasticsearch Domain Without Bypassing AWS Cognito

Tags: nginx, amazon-cognito, nginx-reverse-proxy, aws-elasticsearch

I apologize, in advance - I'm extremely new to Nginx.

I have two VPC-based AWS Elasticsearch Domains, we'll call dev and prod. I want both domains to be inaccessible to the open internet, but available in some networks outside the VPC. To that end, I set them up as VPC-based Elasticsearch domains and planned to use a reverse proxy accessible only from the networks I wish. I've setup the dev cluster, which has no authentication, using an NGINX reverse proxy with the following config:

```
events{

}

http{
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name kibana-dev.[domain name];

    location / {

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
      proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";

      proxy_pass https://[vpc id].[vpc region].es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/;
      proxy_redirect https://[vpc id].[vpc region].es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/ https://kibana-dev.[domain name]/;
    }

      location ~ (/app/kibana|/app/timelion|/bundles|/es_admin|/plugins|/api|/ui|/elasticsearch|/app/opendistro-alerting) {
         proxy_pass          https://[vpc id].[vpc region].es.amazonaws.com;
         proxy_set_header    Host $host;
         proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    }

  }
}
```

This works fine.

For the prod domain, however, I'm running into an issue. I want all users, even those that use the proxy, to have to authenticate with AWS Cognito (so I don't just want to, for example, create an access policy with an IP exception for the proxy's IP address, as that bypasses Cognito).

I have used a similar NGINX config for my "prod" Elasticsearch instance, but with no luck. The Cognito login page redirects to the VPC-based URL after authentication. I've tried manually adding my proxy's URL to the Cognito app's Callback URLs, but it still redirects by default to the VPC-based URL. I've also tried manually changing the redirect URI in the Cognito URL to refer to my proxy, but I've found that after authenticating I'm redirected to the Cognito login page again - perhaps a header or something isn't getting through?

How (or can) I get this running in Nginx, so that users can access the "prod" Elasticsearch domain while still being required to authenticate with AWS Cognito?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh! I should have read the documentation more carefully. AWS provides [an example Nginx conf file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html) for a Kibana proxy with Cognito:

```
{
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name $host;
    rewrite ^/$ https://$host/_plugin/kibana redirect;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /_plugin/kibana {
        # Forward requests to Kibana
        proxy_pass https://$kibana_host/_plugin/kibana;

        # Handle redirects to Cognito
        proxy_redirect https://$cognito_host https://$host;

        # Update cookie domain and path
        proxy_cookie_domain $kibana_host $host;
        proxy_cookie_path / /_plugin/kibana/;

        # Response buffer settings
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }

    location ~ \/(log|sign|fav|forgot|change|saml|oauth2) {
        # Forward requests to Cognito
        proxy_pass https://$cognito_host;

        # Handle redirects to Kibana
        proxy_redirect https://$kibana_host https://$host;

        # Update cookie domain
        proxy_cookie_domain $cognito_host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your cognito user pool and ES domain config for cognito? I try to set up the same and have the above nginx config but no luck when my domain is in VPC.
I get redirect_mismatch error when I try to use the proxy domain as a callback url in cognito

Comment: @TamasSzasz I'm having the same issue. Did you ever manage to get it fixed?

Comment: You get the redirect_mismatch error because after you logged in the redirect_uri query param does not match the allowed redirect_uri in Cognito.

It is likely that the query param as the private URL (vpc-xxx.region.es.amazonaws.com) instead of the public URL you set up Cognito's app client's Callback URL.

In my case, I had to rewrite the location header in order to replace the URL.

Comment: @CaptainH. is this the preferred method? I find it strange that AWS would forget to add this to their tutorials.
I would have thought there is a query param config in opensearch.

Comment: I still could not make the reverse-proxy work, so I contacted the AWS Support that advised me to make the ElasticSearch/OpenSearch public and setup Cognito in front of it, which is what I ended up doing.